# Can I schedule Windows Server Backup using a managed service account?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, service-accounts, windows-server-backup

I've set up a scheduled backup using the Windows Server Backup. Also, I've created a managed service account that should execute the backup, but the Schedule wizard doesn't accept the user account.

The account is granted membership to the Backup Operators group and have all necessary permissions to the backup location.

Is it possible to assign the managed service account to the backup service by other means?

**Update:** since the backup is scheduled using the Task Scheduler in Windows, I've also tried to configure the job to run as a managed service account without success.

Comment: Check Event Viewer, The wizard MUST accept that account, and the account must have the correct permisions. Maybe you need to give it permisions to log on on the server.

Comment: @Carlos - I guess the basic problem is that the wizard requires filling out both username and password. But the whole idea with managed service accounts is that only the AD knows the password, thus I have no password to enter for the account. Leaving the password blank, I can see in the event log that a logon failure is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, guess I found the answer to my own question. According to [the "Managed Services Account" FAQ for Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff641729(WS.10).aspx):

> **Can I use managed service accounts with Task Scheduler?** The use of
>   managed service accounts with Task
>   Scheduler is not supported.

Comment: Hehe, Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 may now support the Task Scheduler with the new Group Managed Service Accounts.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128431.aspx#BKMK_ConfigureServiceIdentity

Comment: "may support"... have you tried it?